# Keep only numbers in a string / remove all non-numbers

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a string column where I only need to the numbers from each string, e.g.

```
A-123  -> 123
456    -> 456
7-X89  -> 789
```

How can this be done in PowerQuery?

Answer (score 9):

Add column. In custom column formula type this one-liner:

```
= Text.Select( [Column], {"0".."9"} )
```

where [Column] is a string column with a mix of digits and other characters. It extracts numbers only. The new column is still a text column, so you have to change the type.

---

**Edit.** If there are dots and minus characters:

```
= Text.Select( [Column1], {"0".."9", "-", "."} ))
```

Alternatively, you can transform the existing column:

```
= Table.TransformColumns( #"PreviousStepName" , {{"Column", each Text.Select( _ , {"0".."9","-","."} ) }} )
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to split the values on each number, and remove blanks from the resulting list.

This result can be used as a new list of delimiters to be used with function Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter to split the original text again and combine the resulting list to the final result.

Explanation: Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter first splits on the first delimiter in the list, then on the second and so on. Note that this function creates a function that must be called with the original string as parameter, so like S.S(delimiters)(string).

Example code:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    NumbersOnly = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"String", (string) => Text.Combine(Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter(List.Select(Text.SplitAny(string,"0123456789"), each _ <> ""))(string))}})
in
    NumbersOnly
```

Comment: Nice solution! Minor suggestion: instead of squeezing all functionality into one line, better split it out into multiple lines - or even better extract it to an own function (with multiple lines) that is then called in TansformColumns. I had to disect your code in PowerQuery to really understand it...

Answer (score 1):

First, create a custom function in PowerQuery using New Query - From Other Sources -> Blank Query. Open the Advanced Editor and paste the following code:

```
(source) => 
let
    NumbersOnly = (char) => if Character.ToNumber(char) >=48 and Character.ToNumber(char) < 58 then char else "",
    Len = Text.Length(source),
    Acc = List.Accumulate(
                   List.Generate( () => 0, each _ < Len, each _ + 1), 
                   "", 
                   (acc, index) => acc& NumbersOnly(Text.At(source, index))
               ),
    AsNumber = Number.FromText(Acc)
in
    AsNumber
```

Name this query `NumbersOnly`.

Now in your main query, add another calculated column where you call this NumbersOnly function with the source column, e.g.:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({[text="A-123"], [text="456"], [text="7-X89"]}),
    Result = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Values", each NumbersOnly([text]), Int64.Type)
in
    Result
```

Comment: "A:123" results in error, as you allow character number 58 which is a colon...
The alternative solution has my preference.

Comment: @MarcelBeug Thanks - fixed the bug. Also replaced List.Generate with List.Accumulate, which seems more appropriate here.