# Extract numbers from text by minimum length of number string using power query

Tags: excel, split, extract, powerquery, text-extraction

**Problem**
I've been tasked to tidy up some very messy data containing a mix of text and numbers and wish to use power query to separate codes from the data. Fortunately, the codes that need separating consist of only numerical values and appear to be 7 characters in length (let's say 6 or greater).

Below is an example of how I wish to separate the data:

[image]

**So Far:**
So Far I have this code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Input ", type text}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","_"," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Input "}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","v"," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Input "}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value1", "TextSplit", each Text.Split([#"Input "], " ")),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "ListTransform", each List.Transform([TextSplit], each Text.Select(_,{"0".."9"}))),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "ListSelect", each List.Select([ListTransform], each Text.Length(_)>=5)),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "TextCombine", each Text.Combine([ListSelect], ", ")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"TextSplit", "ListTransform", "ListSelect"})
```

in
#"Removed Columns"

which does appear to solve the problem. However, in cases like `0102646v2.0` this is pulled through as `010264620`. In order to get it to work, I have had to introduce steps to replace _ and "v" with " ". Is it not possible for Power Query to recognize that say `0102646v2.0` should be extracted as `0102646`?

Data:

```
Input Values:
3159087 v1.0
3194070 v1.0
#8102368 V3.0 (Shine and ProtectR18)
#8102371 V4.0 (Lemon 12A Degreaser)
Marine (FF3080300 v1.0)
Green Apple (FF3080301 v1.0)
0102646v2.0 (Fresh Cotton)
TDS# 3129801 V1.0 GPA Code#3123402
FF3112964 0.1 FF3145524 0.1_3152912 0.1
```

Thank you!

Update: Pulling Version Number

[image]

Regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a PQ implementation of extracting patterns using Regex and returning them comma separated:

Add this as a custom function.  I named it `fnRegexExtr`

```
//see http://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/04/25/regex-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel-with-java-script/
// and https://gist.github.com/Hugoberry/4948d96b45d6799c47b4b9fa1b08eadf

let   fx=(text,regex)=>
    Web.Page(
        "<script>
            var x='"&text&"';
            var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');
            var b=x.match(y);
            document.write(b);
        </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}

in
fx
```

You can then use it in your code like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Input", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Output", 
        each fnRegexExtr([Input], "[0-9]{6,}"))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

which returns:

[image]

Comment: Wow this is interesting. Never realized we could use Regex or Javascript in Power Query

Comment: Looks like it's worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Regex in PQ...nice!

Comment: It'd be nicer if it was built-in

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Is it possible to modify this to also extract numbers less than say 3? I'm trying to also extract the Version number in a separate column. I tried modifying the Function to fnRegexExtr([SDS D Code], "[0-9]{0,3}")) but no success.

Comment: @Nick by `less than 3` do you mean less than the value of 3?  or less than 3 digits long?  What is your input and desired output?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Length. i.e. 321, 21 or 1 but not 4321

Comment: @Nick I'll work on it when I'm back at my computer. Should be possible with word boundaries.

Comment: @Nick Still waiting for example of input and desired output.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Please See update for example

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Also just note for the final example, I just typed the values in as I would expect them. However, my image assumes using V as some sort of Delimiter. If your method were to return 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 as the result that would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Nick OK, it's more of a regex question than a PQ question, but to extract the version number from your sample, you could use, for the regex argument: `[vV]\\S+\\b`

Comment: @JvdV You could use it in the past if you also had Python or R installed. But this is the first I've seen that could do it without other requirements, at least for PQ in Excel (and Power BI desktop). Not sure how efficient with large data though.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Wow that's interesting. What are S and b?

Comment: @Nick Look up one of the many internet references on Regular Expressions for an explanation.

Comment: It's quite slow, but it works. Amazing! I can use JS to solve anything that power query has no functions for like this. Thank you! Let's hope for native regex in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can [extract numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591947/6908282) from a text using the below code:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "MyNumberColumn", each Text.Select([Input], {"0".."9"}))
```

this will give you all the numbers in the same order in the string. And if your actual numbers are exactly 7 characters in length, you should be able to se Excel formula to extract that as well.

Or if you prefer splitting the text using Power Query, you can

1. split the column using number of characters and then (Home > Split Column (drop-down) > By Number of Characters)
2. merge the columns using a delimiter (Select columns > Go to Add Column tab > Merge Columns)

Note: you need to edit the `PreviousStep` and `Input` based on your query

Comment: Hi this is okay however in cases where you have say 31590187 v1.0 the output is 3159018710

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it just now. Ron's answer provides the right output you're looking for