# Extract phrases from cell in power BI Desktop/Queries

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm completely new to Power BI and a bit lost with that tool.

I'm trying to extract phrases from a cell that has a very long string.
Each phrase I'm trying to extract, starts with 'DI' followed by 4 random numbers, so the format is DIXXXX.
There is a random number of such phrases in each cell and they are placed in a random part of the string.
I required each phrase to be extracted to a separate cell.

Please see an example of the long string below

[image]

Additionally, I used to do it in excel, unfortunately, due to a large amount of data it keeps crashing.

The final result in excel looked as below

[image]

Could anyone please advise how could I achieve that in Power Bi

Comment: I suggest using regular expressions. You can implement that either using python, or javascript.  [Extract numbers from text by Minimum Length of Number String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463913/extract-numbers-from-text-by-minimum-length-of-number-string-using-power-query) shows an example of using javascript to be able to use regular expressions in Power Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split column by delimiter (using "DI"), then extract the first 4 digits of each resulting column and then add the prefix back as needed.

Something like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("DI", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}}),
    #"Extracted First Characters" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1", {{"Column1.2", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.3", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted First Characters",{"Column1.1"}),
    #"Added Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {{"Column1.2", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
    #"Added Prefix1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix", {{"Column1.3", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
    #"Added Prefix2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix1", {{"Column1.4", each "DI" & _, type text}})
in
    #"Added Prefix2"
```

Comment: My apologies for the late answer. I've tried this and received the following error: Expression.Error: We couldn't find an Excel table named 'Table1'.
Details:
    Table1

Comment: Table1 is the name of the table in my workbook. Yours might be different.

Comment: No, my table is called Table1 as well, not sure what is wrong can't find the answer for it anywhere.

Comment: That's strange. It's failing at the first step? Maybe instead of pasting the code into the advanced editor, try clicking data -> From Table/Range and then selecting your table. See if it throws the same error.

Comment: Ok, I had some time to play a bit longer with it. So it works when I run it in the Excel Query It doesn't work when I try to run it in the Power Bi query. On top of that, there were a few issues in the output which were a minor fix. pasting my final code as answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText(
          "i45WKsnILFYAokSF4pKizLx0BRdPQyNjE1MgDaLMgLSZuYWlAUxcKVYnWgmhxsTY1MxcAWYIjJ+XX64UGwsA",
          BinaryEncoding.Base64
        ),
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ),
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [Column1 = _t]
  ),
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Column1", type text}}),
  fx =
    let
      fx = (input) =>
        Web.Page(
          "<script>
            var x='"
                    
            & input
            & "';
            var b = x.match(/DI[0-9]{5}/gm);
            document.write(b);
        </script>"


                  
        ){0}[Data]{0}[Children]{1}[Children]
    in
      fx,
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each fx([Column1])),
  #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Text"}, {"Text"}),
  #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Custom", each Text.Split([Text], ",")),
  #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Text"}),
  #"Expanded Custom1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom"),
  #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Custom1", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
    #"Added Index",
    {"Column1"},
    {{"ad", each _, type table [Column1 = nullable text, Custom = text, Index = number]}}
  ),
  #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Grouped Rows",
    "Custom",
    each
      let
        x = [ad],
        #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(x, {{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
        #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index.1", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
        #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index1", {"Index"}),
        #"Added Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(
          #"Removed Columns1",
          {{"Index.1", each "Value" & Text.From(_, "en-US"), type text}}
        ),
        #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(
          #"Added Prefix",
          List.Distinct(#"Added Prefix"[Index.1]),
          "Index.1",
          "Custom"
        )
      in
        #"Pivoted Column"
  ),
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom2", {"Custom"}),
  #"Expanded Custom2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    #"Removed Other Columns",
    "Custom",
    {"Column1", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"},
    {"Column1", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"}
  )
in
  #"Expanded Custom2"
```

Comment: My apologies for the late answer. I've added your code to the custom column formula and It has returned a table for me. Unfortunately, the table has some random values in it. I assume your code refers to a column but I'm not sure which part of the code does it.

Answer (score 0):

Final corrected code that worked for me:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Merged", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("DI", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5","Column1.6","Column1.7","Column1.8","Column1.9","Column1.10"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}, {"Column1.4", type text}, {"Column1.5", type text}, {"Column1.6", type text}, {"Column1.7", type text}, {"Column1.8", type text}, {"Column1.9", type text}, {"Column1.10", type text}}),
    #"Extracted First Characters" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1", {{"Column1.2", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.3", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.4", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.5", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.6", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.7", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.8", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.9", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}, {"Column1.10", each Text.Start(_, 4), type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted First Characters",{"Column1.1"}),
    #"Added Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {{"Column1.2", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
    #"Added Prefix1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix", {{"Column1.3", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
    #"Added Prefix2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix1", {{"Column1.4", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
    #"Added Prefix3" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix2", {{"Column1.5", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
    #"Added Prefix4" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix3", {{"Column1.6", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
#"Added Prefix5" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix4", {{"Column1.7", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
#"Added Prefix6" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix5", {{"Column1.8", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
#"Added Prefix7" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix6", {{"Column1.9", each "DI" & _, type text}}),
#"Added Prefix8" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Prefix7", {{"Column1.10", each "DI" & _, type text}})
in
    #"Added Prefix8"
```